# Loopback-context not reliable - searching for alternative

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have been using **loopback-context** to set the current user object in my middleware after user is authenticated. Since, loopback-context is not reliable, I tried an alternative by fetching the accessToken from request for every api call and setting the user object with the accessTokenId.

However, in my **mixins**, I have a before save hook to update the created_by and modified_by values with current user_id and I'm not able to fetch the current user here.

The code for setting user object in server.js is as follows:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.accessToken) return next();
    app.models.Users.findOne({
       where:
       {id: req.accessToken.userId},
       include: "roles"
    }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
       return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
       return next(new Error("No user with this access token was 
          found."));
    }
    res.locals.currentUser = user;
    next();
    });
});
```

The code in mixins is as follows:

```
    Model.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {
        var loopbackContext = LoopBackContext.getCurrentContext();
        var currentUser = loopbackContext && 
            loopbackContext.get('currentUser');
        let data = ctx.instance || ctx.data;
        if (ctx.isNewInstance && data) {
            // current user not available here
            data.created_by = currentUser && currentUser.id;
            data.modified_by = currentUser && currentUser.id;
        } else if (!ctx.isNewInstance && data) {
            data.modified_at = new Date();
            data.modified_by = currentUser && currentUser.id;
        }
        next();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ctx object instead. Here is a sample Mixin I use in my projects for the same requirement.

```js
//created-modified-injection.js
module.exports = function(Model, options) {
    'use strict';
    Model.defineProperty('created_by', {type: Number});
    Model.defineProperty('updated_by', {type: Number});
    Model.defineProperty('created_date', {type: Date});
    Model.defineProperty('updated_date', {type: Date});    
    Model.observe('before save', function event(ctx, next) {
        const token = ctx.options && ctx.options.accessToken;
        const userId = token && token.userId;
        let date = new Date();
        if (ctx.instance) {
            if (ctx.isNewInstance) {
                ctx.instance.created_by   = ctx.instance.created_by || userId;
                ctx.instance.created_date   = date;
            }else{
                ctx.instance.updated_by   = ctx.instance.updated_by || userId;
                ctx.instance.updated_date   = date;
            }
        }
next();
    });
};
```

And Enable it in your model's mixin

```
"CreatedModifiedInjection": true
```